# authentication for REST API for apps running on desktop on client side

Tags: c#, vb.net, rest, authentication

I need to push data from applications made in VB.net, Java, C#, C++, Node.js and other modern languages to our server. These applications are running in retail stores and our service is 3-party service. I am planning to offer REST API to push the data but my concern is how do I authenticate a  single store.

One of the ways I thought was using the AWS way : AccessKey and Secret Key approach outlined here : 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_Authentication2.html

Each store can have multiple billing machines/computers --> so what will be a better approach to authenticate because the AWS way requires to paste the Keys from our interface to their local machine setups (At this point I am assuming our services will be directly called from the front end application rather than Back-End Servers.

I am confused how to go about approaching this problem - if the REST API Calls should be made from front-end or back-end services and if its front-end how do I go about authenticating the store.

Comment: Have a look at OAuth2, OpenID Connect, IdentityServer, stuff like that. If you want to make your life a little easier and refrain from hosting the auth/auth yourself, there are cloud solutions available like [this](https://auth0.com/).

Comment: Thank you @WimOmbelets . I read about OAuth2 and the different grants - Will it be a good idea to use Password grant where username and password can be taken in an interactive fashion - it supports refresh token as well. I am first creating a prototype using open-source libraries.  In my case Authorization Server and Resource Server will be hosted by the same company. Password grant will also help avoid the problem of URI redirect with other grant types. 

I found node-oauth2-server for Node.js. Do you have any other recommendations for Node.js as backend.

Comment: No sorry, I don't know enough about node to give you any sensible advice.

Answer (score 1):

To first answer

> I am confused how to go about approaching this problem - if the REST
>   API Calls should be made from front-end or back-end services and if
>   its front-end how do I go about authenticating the store.

Since you say

> I need to push data from applications made in VB.net, Java, C#, C++,
>   Node.js and other modern languages to our server.

To me it sounds like you want server (your customers) -> server (your REST API) communication.

Before getting into security options, you need to think about security-ness and time/resources.

Starting with security, if you're dealing with HIPAA, PII or other sensitive data, then definitely do more research.

Next, time/resources. A SaaS service like [AuthRocket](https://authrocket.com/) or [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) will make life much easier, however, it is a monthly expense. You can roll an open source library into your API, you'll just need to spend the time to develop, test and maintain (and deal with stuff like user registration, lost pws, etc).

And so now, authentication. ID/Token auth like Amazon is the most common way. Every REST request a customer issues will include their ID and token (eg `ID=customer-123, Token=laksdjflaksjdf`). To handle a customer w/multiple machines, you can issue n tokens, one for each machine. The customer would be responsible for putting the credentials on each machine. Again, this is the most common way to do things.

You can also use OAuth, but this doesn't make as much sense for your use case since its companies and not individuals (usually OAuth is for developer-oriented APIs).

There are also other various token based authentication approaches, but these are usually better suited for client->API requests (websites->APIs).

Comment: I agree Amazon way would be better.  I can use simple version of AccessKeyId and SecretKey which customers can remember & enter every time they login into the system.  In such scenarios how do customers (store owners) reset the AccessKeyId & SecretKey - I mean many times there machines are allowed to access only the Billing App - I will certainly make available a portal to reset the credentials - so these staff members will go to a common machine where they access the portal - reset the credentials & then use those ?

Comment: Have you seen AWS-like authorization deployments in such context.I am creating APIs for the first time.

Comment: It looks AWS API Gateway supports this type of mechanism where it can allow to generated AccessKey, SecretKey (username, passwd) and then it authenticates the API call as well and help with scaling option.